# Custom Assignment Operator and Iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

I'm having trouble with basic operator overloading. I'm working with the following class:

```
template <class T> 
class Node
{
    public:
        Node() {value = NULL; next = NULL; prev = NULL;}
        T* value;
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;   
};    


class fixedList
{
public:
    class fListIterator
    {
    public:
        Node<T>* point;
        fListIterator & operator=(Node<T>* x) {point = x; return this}
    };

    Node<T>* first;
    Node<T>* last
   fListIterator begin() {fListITerator a = first; return a;}
}

template <class T> fixedList<T>::fixedList(int x, T y)
{
     Node<T> data[x];

     for (int z = 0; z < x; z++)
     {
         data[0].value = &y;
     }

     first = &data[0];
     last = &data[x-1];

     Node<T>* assign = first;

     for (int i = 0; i < x - 1; i++)
     {
         Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
         temp = &data[i];
         assign->next = temp;
         assign->next->prev = assign;
         assign = assign->next;
     }

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    fixedList<int>* test = new fixedList<int>(5, 2);
    fixedList<int>::fListIterator a = test->begin();

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting the error in the begin() function:
"conversion from 'Node*' to non-scalar type 'fixedList::fListIterator' requested"

Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
Apologies, I was trying to keep it compact.

Comment: Show the declaration of `test` and the class definition of `Node`.

Comment: the line that the compiler states the root problem is on would also be helpful (if you could mark it in your question).

Answer (score 0):

When you return `this` in the equal operator, the program is trying to return the `Node*` that you called it from (since it accepts `Node<T>*` as the argument).

Comment: How would I get it to return the object then?

Comment: Well it looks to me like you want the function to return a `fixedList::fListIterator*` instead of `Node<T>*`, so try changing it to that.  I think an implicit conversion may be taking place when you call `test->begin()` (from fListIterator to Node*), and that is why you are having the problem at that location.

Answer (score 0):

`fListIterator begin() {fListITerator a = first; return a;}`

The statement `fListITerator a = first;` is a construction. You are attempting to call a constructor of `fListIterator` taking a `Node<T>*` as an argument - except you don't have one !

If you break this code in two statements :

`fListIterator begin() {fListITerator a; a = first; return a;}`

It will :

- construct `a` with the default constructor of `fListIterator` (since you didn't explicitly provided a constructor, the compiler automatically generated one for you);
- assign `first` to `a` using your `operator=` overload;
- properly return `a`

You should be careful however : just as user1167662's answer is specifying, your `fListIterator::operator=` is not returning the proper value. `this`, in this situation, is of type `fListIterator*`.